# Database not importing

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

### Error

---

##

> ```
> --
> ```
>
> ### -- Database: `verticalned`
>
> ### -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> -- Table structure for table `announcements`

```
CREATE TABLE  `announcements` (
    `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL , 
    `description` VARCHAR( 6000 ) DEFAULT NULL  , 
    `links` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `first` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT > NULL , 
    `second` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `third` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `fourth` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `staff` VARCHAR( 22 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `time` DATETIME( 2 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
    `subject` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(2) DEFAULT NULL,   `subject` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT ' at line 20

---

### version

---

---

[image]

Comment: strange your `create table`...it runs on my end.

Comment: its running on my system as well but its giving error when i am importing it on the web server.

Comment: VARCHAR in mysql is 255 maximum,you have a 6000,also datetime doesnt take a number.

Comment: Please include MySQL server version you use, ideally for both systems you use

Comment: The script above would fail on your DB server version 5.5.55 (see my answer below). What DB server (not client!) version do you use locally when the script is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the mysql version you are using (probably older than 5.6.4) does not accept precision (fractional seconds). You can **bypass** the issue by replacing `..., time DATETIME(2) DEFAULT NULL ,...` with `... , time DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,...`.

However, you should **solve** the issue by either changing the data type to `timestamp` or upgrading MySQL server to a version later than 5.6.4

Comment: `TIMESTAMP(2)` was also introduced in 5.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `announcements` ( 
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
`description` VARCHAR(6000) DEFAULT NULL, 
`links` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`first` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`second` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`third` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`fourth` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`staff` VARCHAR( 22 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`time` DATETIME( 2 ) DEFAULT NULL , 
`subject` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

obvoiusly theres nothing wrongn with your code. just add the slanted quotes

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE  announcements (
    `id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `description` VARCHAR( 6000 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
    `links` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
     first`TINYINT DEFAULT NULL ,`

second`TINYINT    DEFAULT NULL,`

third`TINYINT  DEFAULT NULL ,`
fourth`TINYINT      DEFAULT NULL,`

staff`VARCHAR(22) DEFAULT NULL ,`

time`DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,`
subject` VARCHAR( 100 ) DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

Please remove character number from INT and TINYINT, and add the slanted quotes your code should work.

Comment: sir its not working still. And i dont understand why should i remove length from INT and TINYINT fields.

Comment: INT and TINYINT size is fixed so it is not needed. time is constant so write it [time] withing box bracket